# NSIS ExecWait and the OSQL application

Tags: sql, sql-server, nsis, osql

I am writing an installer which should perform some MSSQL database operations. These operations are in a .cmd file and are performed through OSQL.exe in MSSQL Server 2000.

Now comes my problem. When I double-click the batch file, it executes OK. However if I run it via ExecWait in my installer (or Exec, or ExecShell, tried all, makes no difference), Windows says that the command osql is not found... The current working directory set via SetOutPath is the very same directory my .cmd file is located in.

I also tried simplifying the case as much as this:

```
sql.cmd:

osql
pause
```

Whereas in my NSIS source I have:

```
Section "Perform DB operations" SEC03
  ReadEnvStr $0 SYSTEMDRIVE
  SetOutPath "$0\DBUtils"
  SetOverwrite try
  File /r "..\source_files\DBUtils\*"
  ExecWait '"$0\DBUtils\sql.cmd"'
SectionEnd
```

My problem happens here, too. By double-clicking or by calling the .cmd from the command line it executes okay, but NSIS's Exec, for some mysterious reason, doesn't seem to find osql. Does anybody have an idea why it could happen?

Answer (score 0):

Where in your hard disk is osql.exe? Try to modify your cmd to use absolute paths.

You can check the PATH your installer sees with:

```
ReadEnvStr $0 PATH
MessageBox MB_OK "PATH: $0"
```

I'm not sure, but maybe if your installer runs as a different user (Administrator), then it could have a different path...

Comment: Hi! It's under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\OSQL.exe , C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\ is included in the PATH environment variable. I'll definitely try changing everything to absolute paths. However, the problem is that the .cmd performs the DB operations not directly for my program but it belongs to a third party component. Therefore I'd rather leave the third-party supplied .cmd file unchanged.

Comment: It works with an absolute path. However, it would be great to discover why it doesn't work with a relative path. By the way I tried changing osql to some Windows executables which should be in the PATH, such as calc or wordpad, and they do work.